# Good books on text mining?

Tags: references, text-mining

Hi I wanted to know if there are some good books on text mining and classification with some case studies?. If not some papers/journals accessible to public would do. If they illustrate their examples with R even better. 
I am not looking for step by step manual but something which illustrates the pros and cons of various text mining approaches to various classes of problems.

Answer (score 5):

Check out
http://lintool.github.com/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf
Data-Intensive Text Processing with  MapReduce - this book is fairly academic but covers a number of commonly used text processing techniques and how they can be parrallised over large dataset using map reduce.

[www.rtexttools.com](http://www.rtexttools.com)
This is an excellent R package which helps you to appply a wide range of classification algorithms (including some ensemble methods) to text analytics.
and

Comment: To make this answer self-contained, would you mind providing a brief summary of each link?

Answer (score 4):

I have recently read four books in this field:

> Feldman, R. and James Sanger, J. (2006). *The Text Mining Handbook:
>   Advanced Approaches in Analyzing Unstructured Data.* Cambridge
>   University Press.

This one focuses on practical examples, software and applied text mining. It gives multiple examples of practical usage of text-mining. It could be of interest if you want to read about commercial applications of text-mining tools.

> Srivastava, A.N. and Sahami, M. (2009). *Text Mining: Classification,
>   Clustering, and Applications.* Chapman & Hall/CRC.

It is series of research papers that are used as examples of usage of different text-mining tools. It is rather too focused as for introductory test.

> Weiss, S.M., Indurkhya, N., Zhang, T. and Damerau, F. (2005). *Text
>   Mining: Predictive Methods for Analyzing Unstructured Information.*
>   Springer.

Very introductory text that describes some general issues.

> Manning, C. (1999). *Foundations of Statistical Natural Language
>   Processing.* MIT Press.

This is **the best** book that I already read on this topic. It is well written, clear, goes deeper into theory but in practice-friendly way. Starts with general introduction, but than reviews some of the most commonly used methods and algorithms. If you would have to choose only a single book, I would recommend this one.

You could also easily find multiple books on natural language processing and text mining that focus on using R (*tm* library) or Python (*nltk* library).

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly on point for what you are looking for, but [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922570.do) by Jeffrey Friedl is a great source for learning how to use regular expressions to parse text. He doesn't discuss modeling techniques, but, armed with counts from applying regular expressions, you could apply a variety of standard modeling approaches.

Answer (score 2):

One book I go back to time and again for ideas is [Text Mining: Predictive Methods...](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441929967) by Sholom Weiss.  It has lots of ideas for approaching problems which I find useful since sometimes text mining is about trying different things - Global vs Local dictionary, number of features to keep, etc.  I find this book to be a good idea generator.  It also has case studies.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest NLP at http://www.nltk.org/ is free and couples with NLTK in python. all the best