# Features for clustering short text

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, natural-language

Say I have a toy dataset as follows:

```
Harry Potter and 
Harry Potter and the Goblet of 
Goblet of Fire 
Harry Sorcer's Stone 
Harry Potter and the Sorcer
of The Rings
The Lord of the Rings 
The Lord of
```

Each of the above is part of, or the full title, of a book. In the example above there are Harry Potter Books and Lord of the Rings Books. If I wanted to cluster these by book (say Harry Potter is cluster 0 and Lord of the Rings is cluster 1) would the following approach be appropriate:

Approach: To preprocess the data I would keep only letters, lowercase letters, remove stop words, and tokenize. I would then use a tf-idf feature vector with K-Means clustering. Is there a better or more sound approach for this kind of problem? This is not limited to Harry Potter or Lord of the Rings books, there could be thousands of different books. Thanks!

**EDIT:** What are some alternative features that are used for clustering short text? It seems that the tf-idf features are very sparse.

Comment: The *words* are not enough to cluster this. If you have just the words, "Goblet of fire" is not at all related to "Harry Potter": zero words in common. You need more and better data.

Comment: It's ok that they are not perfectly clustered together, but I guess i'm just wondering what some good features to use for short text clustering are. It seems that if I have huge documents then tf-idf is fine but with very short documents such as I have the vectors are very sparse

Comment: "Goblet of fire" and "The Lord of" have a word in common, "of". They will be clustered.

Comment: so would using tfidf and KMeans be ok to use to cluster these words then? If there are words in common across short documents can we use tfidf and KMeans?

Comment: It will merge ***way* too many false positives**, and will fail to merge those that you want. Because you have too little data.

Comment: I actually have thousands of short documents above was just a toy example but I am unsure of other features that are more appropriate for these short documents

Comment: You need *longer* documents for tf-idf, cosine, k-means, etc. to work. With such short text, and a large quantity, everything will be connected in particiular by such garbage words. The point is: the short texts itself do not contain enough*information* to make an unsupervised clustering applicable. It will not work, you are expecting the impossible to happen.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do, it to fill-in the missing parts of titles to re-create the original titles, so you want to do something similar to what spell-corrector algorithm does with misspelled words. Basically what you want to do is to use some kind of [distance metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)) (see [this book](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240684/online-course-about-distance-measures/240692#240692), or [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.332.4480&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), like [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), [TF-IDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), [Jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) etc. and use it for binding together the similar observations. The choice for the appropriate distance metric will highly depend on your data and your aim, so it is a decision that *you* have to make, possibly by trial-and-error. Since distance metric will just measure the distance for you, next you would have to decide on empirical basis on some cut-off to build a decision rule for classifying the cases. You may want to [read more on text mining](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/193049/35989) before proceeding further.

Comment: I guess I am more interested in knowing if there are better features, which I am sure there are, to use than tf-idf for clustering short text documents

Comment: If I limit the max feature vector to say 100-200 for tf-idf I think my clusters might be alright, but I am not sure of some other specific features for short text